# What could reset the hostname of a server?

Tags: debian

After upgrading some servers to Debian Linux 6.0, from time to time I find the server hostname reset to (none). How could I track what process does that and avoid this situation?

I am a programmer, not an administrator. As I don't know all the specifics of Linux, I am using Virtualmin and Webmin to administer those servers.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow [HowTo/ChangeHostname - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname) and set it to whatever you want, however it sounds like `Webmin` and/or `Virtualmin` is misbehaving (try to update it to latest version, if problem still there you might want to submit bug report).

Comment: Yes, I found a way how to set it back manually, but once in a while I find it set to (none) again.